# jQuery - Scale anchor on mouseover

Tags: jquery, effects

Can anyone tell me why this one isn't working?

```
 $(".stage a").live("mouseover", function(){ 
       $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 200 }, 200);
 });
```

Animate height & width work - I'm just trying to simplify the function. I'm trying to get the [hoverpulse](http://malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/) plugin effect without adding it.

Also can anyone confirm that "hover" doesn't work with .live?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Also can anyone confirm that "hover"
>   doesn't work with .live?

[official docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) show "hover" isn't supported by "live":

> Possible event values: click,
>   dblclick,  mousedown, mouseup,
>   mousemove, mouseover, mouseout,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup Currently not
>   supported: blur, focus, mouseenter,
>   mouseleave, change, submit

Comment: Per the docs, also, "hover" is equivalent to "mouseenter" and "mouseleave".

Answer (score 1):

`effect()` is not a jQuery function, that may explain why isn't working unless you're using some plugin you haven't mentioned.

To achive the hoverpulse effect I think you need to change the height and width of the element but also it's position to make it looks like a zoom instead of a resize. After you calculate the new height, width, top and left attributes (if the element is absolutely positioned) you can use `animate()` like this:

```
$(this).animate({width:w, height:h, top: t, left: l}, 200);
```

The hoverpluse plugin also changes the *zoomed* element's z-index attribute to a higher value to put the element on top of the other ones.

Comment: He's probably using jQuery UI

Answer (score 1):

```
$("id_for_dom_element").hover(
function{
//Here comes what you wanna do when the mouse is on the element
},
function(){
//Here comes what you wanna do when the mouse leaves the element
}
);
```